# I get an ERROR when using REGEXMATCH

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I am trying to use =REGEXMATCH(A1, "good") ; but this creates an error and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried `=REGEXMATCH(A1; "good")`

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jacob. Your image shows that you are in the Czech Republic, where the local equivalent of the US comma to separate formula parameters is a semicolon.

You may want to note that commas used to indicate horizontal elements in a virtual array are replaced with the backslash character in the Czech Republic, e.g., instead of `={"yes","no"}`, you would use `={"yes"\"no"}`.